# Does a recipe provided as DEPENDS can have own do_install() in yocto?

Tags: yocto, recipe

I am trying to build a custom recipe with Yocto (Rocko) for my Linux i.MX6 based embedded system.
The main recipe had dependency on a other custom recipe(as the main recipe is using header-files from this recipe) which is also creating some binaries which needs to be included in the final image.

I have added other_recipe(nbdkit) in the "DEPENDS" of main_recipe.bb

```
DEPENDS += "nbdkit"
```

the main recipe is creating a .so with the help of its own source file which is including header-files from the 'kit' recipe. I am able to install the binaries & .so generated using this main_recipe by adding it in do_install().

Now in the other_recipe(nbdkit http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-networking/recipes-support/nbdkit/nbdkit_git.bb?h=master), When I add do_install()to include the binaries generated from that recipe the main_recipe build gets failed with PKG_CONFIG error as follow,

```
| Package nbdkit was not found in the pkg-config search path.
| Perhaps you should add the directory containing `nbdkit.pc'
| to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
| No package 'nbdkit' found
```

Other build errors says that the header-files of kit included in the main_recipe is not found.

```
app-nbdkit-plugin.c:2:10: fatal error: nbdkit-plugin.h: No such file or directory
```

Where app-nbdkit-plugin.c is source file of main_recipe & kit-plugin.h is header file of other_recipe.

The strange thing is, when I remove do_install() from other_recipe(nbdkit) the main_recipe is getting built successfully.
Now I doubt, Is it possible to set a recipe as DEPENDS of other recipe and at the same time it provides output file as do_install()?
Will sharing header-files from other_recipe to main_recipe resolves the issue? If yes, how to do that?

Thanks.

[EDIT] Added nbdkit recipe link.

Comment: Check what actually gets packaged (and in which package) by kit build when you modify it. To get any more useful advice you really do need to publish more than one line of your recipes...

Comment: @JussiKukkonen kit recipe is actually nbdkit recipe given at http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-networking/recipes-support/nbdkit/nbdkit_git.bb?h=master. To include nbdkit binary in to the final image I have added do_install() in this recipe having single line as "install -m 0755 ${S}/nbdkit ${D}${bindir}"

Comment: @JussiKukkonen I am trying to prepare it's plugin in my application source which using header files from this recipe. I have included nbdkit as DEPENDS in the application recipe. As I mentioned, If I don't add do_install() in the nbdkit recipe then it works fine. adding do_install() in this recipe gives error.

Comment: I suggest first taking a look at what files get packaged and in which packages (e.g. in $WORKDIR/packages-split/) both before and after your change. It sounds like you are overriding the normal autotools install: this sounds like a bad idea. Are you sure that the binary isn't already packaged or that you cannot configure the software so that the default "make install" actually installs what you want?

Comment: You;re not "adding" do_install, you're overriding it. Please use `do_install_append() {}` in your recipe otherwise you mess up with the do_install that comes from inherited classes. As Jussi suggested, check without your do_install where the nbdkit binary is installed with `oe-pkgdata-util find-path '/usr/bin/nbdkit'` and add this package to the image recipe.